# Multidimensions in a database

Tags: database, database-schema

I have several same structured tables with config information. E.g. table1, table2... The amount of tables is dynamic. Is there a way of storing these configurations in a database without making a new (same structured) table for each configuration ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create one table.

If TableA is (ID, Name, Value) and TableB is (ID, Name, Value)

TableAll is (ID, TableType, Name, Value)

for example.